# How to make jasmin test keep running until expect succeeds?

Tags: jasmine

I am testing a background process API. This API call returns messages at regular intervals. I am trying to write a test that waits until it gets the specific message I am looking for.

Example:

```
describe('integration tests', function() {
   it('expecting a specific message', async (done) => {
      const callback = (message) => {
         if (message === ''Hello world') {
            expect(message).toEqual('Hello world');
         }
      };
      await someApiCall(callback);
   });
});
```

In the above example, I am passing a callback to the background process api call. The process executes the callback at regular intervals with different messages. There is no guarantee that I will get `Hello World` on the first execution. That's why I had to wrap `expect` inside `if` statement so that the test will not fail on message mismatch. So, I want to keep checking for some X amount of time and then fail if I did not get that specific message within that time.

Is there a better way I can test this? placing `expect` inside `if` seems bad.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `done` function, `async` is not needed. I also noticed that in your example, you create a `callback` function but don't use it. I assume the `callback` to be an  argument of the `someApiCall` function. If this is the case, you could write your test as follows.

```
it('expecting a specific message', () => {
   const callback = (message) => null; 
   someApiCall(callback);
   jasmine.clock().tick(10000);
   expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello world');
});
```

It could also work with the `done` function.

```
it('expecting a specific message', (done) => {
    const maxCallbackInvocations = 10;
    let callbackInvocations = 0;
    const callback = (message) => {
       callbackInvocations++;
       if (message === 'Hello world') {
           expect(1).toBe(1);
           done();
       } else if (callbackInvocations >= maxCallbackInvocations) {
           fail();
       }
    };
    someApiCall(callback);
};
```